# What is the highest combination of certain values in a table given a certain restriction

Tags: r

I am currently working on the so-called "Moneyball" problem. I am basically trying to select the best combination of three baseball players (based on certain baseball-relevant statistics) for the least amount of money.
I have the following dataset (OBP, SLG, and AB are statistics that describe the performance of a player):

```
# the table has about 100 observations;
# the data frame is called "batting.2001"

playerID    OBP         SLG         AB   salary

giambja01   0.3569001   0.6096154   20   410333
heltoto01   0.4316547   0.4948382   57   4950000
berkmla01   0.2102326   0.6204506   277  305000
gonzalu01   0.4285714   0.3880131   409  9200000
martied01   0.4234079   0.5425532   100  5500000
```

My goal is to pick three players who in combination have the highest possible sum of OBP, SLG, and AB, but at the same time do not exceed a total salary of 15.000.000 dollar.

My approach so far has been rather simple... I just tried to arrange (in descending order) the columns OBP, SLG, and AB and simply picking the three players on the top that in combination do not exceed the salary restriction of 15 Million dollar:

```
batting.2001 %>%
   arrange(desc(OPB), desc(SLG), desc(AB))
```

Can anyone of you think of a better solution? Also, what if I would like to get the best combination of three players for the least amount of money? What approach would you use in that scenario?

Thanks in advance, and looking forward to reading your solutions.

Comment: What you are doing right now is essentially a greedy algorithm. Optimal solution is not guaranteed. You should look into linear programming libraries ex. `lpsolve`. Depending on how many players you have, you could also consider brute force method i.e generate all combinations of 3 players and evaluate sum of OBP, SLG, and AB while discarding combinations that exceed total salary of $15MM.